# Pure CSS book cover flip on page load after delay

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to make a page transition that starts as a "book cover" on only a main content div, not the whole page. You can see the cover for a few seconds, long enough to have a good glance at it. Then the cover is supposed to "open" like any hardback book cover opens, lifting up front one side to then flip out of view as if zoomed in on the inner page and the cover is out of frame.

I've looked at so many tutorials and generators and there seems to be some sort of "holy grail" of flipping, where the item flips horizontally on its y-axis in the center, like flipping a card over. I can't find anything that helps me figure out how to flip from just one side across to the other, just like a hardback book cover would do.

I can't provide a code snippet as I literally don't know where to begin. I could load in one of a zillion sample codes from one of a zillion tutorial pages but it would just be random, meaningless animated flipping code that I would have zero understanding of how to customize to do what I need, otherwise I'd have done it already and not be here.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Even if you just point me at a tutorial page for some generic animated flipping code and simply tell me what attributes to alter to get it to flip open like a hardcover book, that would be perfect.

I think I can figure out how to get it to trigger after a pause on loading using delays, but if you have a better solution, that's welcome as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll walk you through it:

1. First, we need a HTML structure, so we create 'pages' (or page sides actually):

```html
    <div class="page odd" id="cover">This is the cover</div>
    <div class="page even" id="cover_back">Inside of the cover</div>
    <div class="page odd" id="content">This is where the content goes...</div>
```

2. Second, we have to position these pages. The odd ones should be in the center and the even ones should be vertically centered but to the left of the odd pages. This is done with the following CSS:

```css
    .page {
        display: inline-block;
        z-index: 1;  /* the content page should go behind the cover pages */
        position: fixed;

        /* Size & Position */
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 360px;
        margin-left: -180px; /* half of width */
        height: 500px;
        margin-top: -250px; /* half of height */
 
        /* Add some styling, so the pages are opaque */ 
        background-color: #eee;
    
        /* Hide backface of each page/side, so we don't see it when turned */
        backface-visibility: hidden;
  
        /* Set up animation */
        transition: transform 1.0s ease;
  
        /* Hide content that overflows the page */
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .page.even {
        margin-left: -540px; /* 1,5 x width to position it left of odd pages */
    }
```

3. When unturned, the odd sides face the viewer, and even sides don't (like a real book). This can be done by using `transform: rotateY()`. The odd pages flip at the left side, even pages at the right. So we add these `transform-origin`'s to the `.page.odd` and `.page.even` classes:

```css
    .page.odd {
        transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    }

    .page.even {
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        transform: rotateY(180deg); /* even pages start rotated (closed book) */
    }
```

4. When you 'turn a page', two sides have to be rotated (1 odd, 1 even), so the odd side doesn't face the viewer anymore and the even side will. You can do this by adding the `.turn` class to these sides. In these `.turn` classes you set the appropriate `transform: rotateY()`'s for odd and even sides:

```css
    .page.odd.turn {
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
    .page.even.turn {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
```

5. To make everything look nice and smooth, we add `perspective: 1200px;` to the body's CSS and make sure the html and body elements are `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`.
6. Final touch: we want the cover pages to go in front of the content page, so we set the `z-index`es of these pages:

```css
    #cover {
        z-index: 3;
    }
    #cover_back {
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

To start you off, I made a example with comments in the CSS to help you out: https://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/b52dw42d/12/

The turning of the page in my example is done by clicking the button, but you probably want to change the JavaScript to use a `setTimeout()` to fire the `.toggleClass('turn')` after X ms.

I also made a example where the turning happens using CSS `animation`: https://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/b52dw42d/11/

Comment: That's really elegant code! Thank you so much! I think I can modify this to do exactly what I want. Very kind of you to help! Is there some sort of "Stack"y way to thank you, like transferal of points or something?

Comment: Is there anyway to use pure CSS for loading the page flip? I found this code that seems to work. I tried using their ideas in with your code but didn't quite get it right. Any suggestions how to fit that in? https://jsfiddle.net/HidetoK/t0e6rsee/1/

Comment: For the change in css (the turning), I'm using a class switch. You could also set these css changes of all the different `.turn` classes inside a css animation and use the `animation-delay` to let it happen after x (milli)secondes. So each class / element that has a `.turn` variant/change should have it's own `animation` (all with the same delay of course)

Comment: Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/b52dw42d/11/

Don't forget to unset the animation for the last odd page (content), since this one shouldn't turn over. I updated all browser prefixes in both examples. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: That's GORGEOUS!!! Thank you so much! When I've finished the page, I'll post it for you to see so you can see how you directly made my project so much cooler and see what I did with your code. :)

Comment: @Hideto, out of curiousity: is your project finished? (Looking forward to the result :) )

Comment: My apologies for not replying sooner. Swamped with stuff. Your solution is gorgeous but does not seem to work with my flex box code, and I've got to release this webpage very soon. It's not your code that's the problem. I'm probably just not advanced enough to know how to fit your code in right. If you want to peek, though, the page that should use your code is: http://www.cafenocturne.com/staff.html - It has a basic stylesheet and its own staff stylesheet. You can click around to look at the other pages, too, if you'd like. Don't bother with the forum. It's dead. :P

Comment: Thanks again for your elegant code. I wish I could've figured my own way how to use it better. That's my job, not yours.